# Which species was Matsya avatar of?

Tags: vaishnavism, brahma, reference-request, matsya

[Matsya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/matsya) is commonly stated as the first or second in the list of major avatars of Vishnu. There are many different versions of the story, varying in details, but with the basic story alike: the Matsya Purana, the Mahabharata, the Shatapatha Brahmana etc. all give different accounts. But I have rarely found any reference on which exact species he was born to. There are claims that Matsya had a horn (to which either a rope or Shesha was tied), in some places he is even depicted in a semi-anthropomorphic form.

Recently, in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/chitala_chitala) on the Sitol fish, in the section titled 'In religion', I found the claim that at least in some versions, Matsya is associated with the Sitol fish. The section refers to a [Thai website](http://huexonline.com/knowledge/20/81). I don't know Thai, but a google translation shows that most of the details on the site are correct. So based on that I feel there must be some valid basis of the Sitol fish claim as well.

However, the site is a secondary reference. I couldn't find any primary reference (which Purana, Itihasa, commentary or perhaps folk beliefs of some region) for which exact species of fish Matsya was.

I understand that different sources may give different answers. Does anyone know of a primary source where it is stated that Matsya was a sitol fish?